# Are 'voltage stabilizers' a scam?

Tags: electrical, saturn

I have a 2002 Saturn SC2. I was told that adding a voltage stabilizer could improve its performance. Is this true? The units appear to simply be some capacitors hooked up between the battery terminals. Here's a link to the website for one such product: 
http://pivotjp.com/product/raizin/raizin-e.html

Comment: They are offering a product with an *82% Improved Performance **Recognizability***. To me, this means they installed it, told their audience they did *something* to the car, and now, can you *feel the difference*? Show me some empirical data and I might believe it. As it is, it's just a scam ... that is JMHO, though.

Comment: Capacitors in that application have one purpose: to provide a momentary burst of current beyond what the electrical system is capable of delivering. More specifically, they have a place in high-power car audio, preventing the voltage dips (headlight dimming) caused by momentary high current draws. In any other scenario it would be entirely useless.

Answer (score 2):

Being a skeptic about such things, I did some research on the internet about the voltage stabilizers. There seems to be several different manufacturers out there, which all claim the same basic thing:

> - Improved audio quality.
> - Increased torque and response and power.
> - Stabilized idling and improved engine kick over.
> - Increased headlight brightness.
> - Improved fuel economy.
> - Improved battery life.

Since you asked about performance, I'll focus on the that portion of it. The claim on the Raizin website states that:

> 82% Improved Performance Recognizability - From a group of 50 monitors, 41 sensed a performance improvement.

What does this actually mean? ***Absolutely nothing.*** Why? It's all subjective. On their website, there is absolutely no empirical data showing there was an improvement. No dyno pulls before and after. Nothing. They were relying on Seat-Of-The-Pants-Dyno to provide them with whether there was an improvement or not. Even the most calibrated butt needs about a 15-20hp difference for the change to be noticeable.

I was able to find [these before/after dyno runs](http://www.superstreetonline.com/how-to/interior-electrical/impp-1010-voltage-stabilizers-can-increase-power-and-torque-fact-fiction/) out there for consumption. The most they registered was an approximate 3hp gain. There is no way anyone, even with a butt with hemorrhoids, could tell the difference of 3hp.

***NOTE:*** I am very skeptical of the dyno charts they present on the given website. There is an issue with how they present the graphs. Because HP is a mathematical derivative of the torque output, they will ***always*** intersect each other at 5,252 rpm. If you look at the dyno graphs they present, they cross somewhere near 4,750 rpm. Due to this, I'm doubting the veracity of the chart itself. They may have, however, just copied the data over wrong, or something else rather stupid.

My bottom line here: **The capacitors do not do what they say they do for performance.** I will grant you that 3hp is still 3hp, though. I guess if you are looking for that last ounce of go power from your car, you could get one, but I'm not seeing enough improvement to warrant it.